# Possible to use the same ssd for a Windows and a Mac laptop via different partitions?

Tags: windows, partition, ssd

So my main laptop is a MacBook which runs on a Samsung 850 evo ssd, has 2 partitions- one runs El Capitan and other is formatted as exfat.

My questions is - how can I use this very ssd to run Windows 10 on my other (HP) laptop off the exfat partition?

Situation as of now - I have a bootable usb of Windows 10 but it asks for a cd disk, and I can't seem to find a way to use the usb.

What I fear is that by using a recovery cd to install Windows, **the program might overwrite over all my existing data. What I want is to just install Windows on the exfat partition**

I understand that unlike Mac, Windows has to be installed separately for each and every computer, I can't use some other laptops ssd to boot this laptop.

Any help or comments are appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Im gonna use the ssd as an internal ssd on the HP laptop,  not as an external with an enclosure. Its my fathers old work laptop and i have standing instructions to not to edit anything on it (but the damn thing is  running windows 7), since there will come a day when he'll have to return it. This is why i wanna 'preserve' the partition with el capitan. I will not be connecting-disconnecting it again and again. Jist twice. I have since formatted the partition in NTFS.

**so my ultimate question is this : I have a drive with two partitions,  I want to install windows 10 on just one while the other partition remains untouched. Since its too messy to install windows on 1 device and then port it to other,  I have inserted the ssd in the new laptop.  How do I move forward with the installation? **

Comment: We you confused me. What year MacBook? I doubt you can run Windows 10 on a ExFat partition. Windows 10 needs to be installed on a NTFS partition. I assume this SSD is inside your MacBook. Is this correct? Is bootable usb of Windows 10 for installing windows 10 or is this actually an installed Windows 10?

Comment: I was assuming it's in an external enclosure - but either way I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Tetsujin: If external, then you could use the Mac to transfer the installation files to the SSD, but I have no idea if the HP is capable of running Windows on an external SSD. Most newer Macs can, but HP uses different firmware.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a better fit for [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions) as it's mainly about PC/Windows rather than Mac.

However, as a rough guide -
you'd do far better to clone the Mac's boot & recovery partitions to a spare drive using something like [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) then let the Windows installer [from a PC] just break the whole darn thing - which it will, it will insist on NTFS & will probably set up its own EFI & recovery partitions; and Windows won't boot easily if it's not at the beginning - then use the Mac to restore the 2 Mac partitions afterwards to the end of the disk.  This will likely need 3rd Party software, such as [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/)

Windows also is not truly portable like macOS, so each time you move it to a different machine it will either crash/fail or require re-authorisation from Microsoft. Windows is also not too keen on booting from a removable drive.

Ultimately, I think buying a second SSD would be simplest & safest.

Answer (score 1):

First, Windows does not run on ExFAT; Windows *requires* NTFS.

Secondly, this is a bad idea all around.  The SATA cables/connectors are not designed to be a device that can be connected/disconnected repeatedly.

You could potentially damage the connectors on your drive, damage the cable itself (where applicable) or worse, the connectors on the logic board.  This is not a path I would advise.

Can you do it?  Technically speaking, yes.  *Should you do it?*  Absolutley not.  Get a new drive.